# How to add extra column in Summarize in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm new to Kusto and I'm trying to do grouping using `summarize` where I can specify additional columns to display for the value on which I'm grouping.

This is what I'm trying to do, mentioned in standard SQL:

```
select UserId, LocationId, COUNT(*) as ErrorCount from SampleTable where ResultType != 'Success'
group by UserId
order by ErrorCount desc
```

I'm grouping by `UserId`, but then I'm displaying the `LocationId` for that `UserId` too in the grouping result

Converting the above to Kusto, I am writing this:

```
SampleTable
| where ResultType != "Success"
| summarize ErrorCount=count() by UserId
| project UserId, LocationId, ErrorCount
| sort by ErrorCount desc
```

But it doesn't work. Kusto complains that it cannot determine was `LocationId` is in the 4th line. I verified using Kusto's `explain` keyword that I'm writing the correct Kusto query. So what's the problem ?

Answer (score 5):

if you want to have `LocationId` as one of the aggregation keys, you should include it in the call to `summarize`, as follows: `| summarize ErrorCount = count() by UserId, LocationId`.

[otherwise, please clarify the output schema you're expecting (ideally, alongside providing a sample input data set, using the `datatable` operator: [datatable operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/datatableoperator)

Comment: This made all my dreams come true.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just a friendly reminder of your original SQL code

```
select UserId, LocationId, COUNT(*) as ErrorCount from SampleTable where ResultType != 
'Success'
group by UserId
order by ErrorCount desc
```

which might contain an error:

**LocationId** is missing from the GROUP BY clause.

Correct SQL code should be:

```
select UserId, LocationId, COUNT(*) as ErrorCount from SampleTable where ResultType != 
'Success'
group by UserId, LocationId
order by ErrorCount desc
```

I think this might be the reason why you accidentally missed LocationId from the summarize clause in the Kusto code.