# Kusto summarize 3 or more columns

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Is there a way to use *summarize* to group 3 or more columns? I've been able to successfully get data from 1 or 2 columns then group by another column, but it breaks when trying to add a 3rd. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58808654/how-to-add-extra-column-in-summarize-in-kusto) asks how to add a column, but only regards adding a 2nd, not a 3rd or 4th. Using the sample help cluster on Azure Data Explorer and working with the Covid19 table, ideally I would be able to do this:

```
Covid19
| summarize by Country, count() Recovered, count() Confirmed, count() Deaths
| order by Country asc
```

And return results like this

[image: Expected results]

But that query throws an error "Syntax Error. A recognition error occurred. Token: Recovered. Line: 2, Position: 36"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the right basic idea, you just can't use count repeatedly inline like that. You can use sum, dcount, or max:

```
Covid19
| summarize sum(Recovered), sum(Confirmed), sum(Deaths) by Country
| order by Country asc
```

Another example:

```
Covid19
| where Timestamp == max_of(Timestamp, Timestamp)
| summarize confirmedCases = max(Confirmed), active = max(Active), recovered = max(Recovered), deaths = max(Deaths) by Country
| order by Country asc
```

In this example I'm getting the latest data for each of the selected columns. Since I initially used the *where* clause to get the latest data you would think I could just list the columns, but when using *summarize* you have to use an aggregate function so I used *max* on each column